# Force an indent in Python code for organizational purposes

Tags: python, indentation

Is there a way to force an indent in Python?
I kind of want it for the sake of making the code look organized.
As an example:

```
# How it looks now
class Bro:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = 1
        self.head.eye = 2
        self.head.nose = 1
        self.head.mouth = 1
        self.neck = 1
        self.torso = 1

# How it'd look ideally (indenting sub-variables of 'head')
class Bro:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = 1
            self.head.eye = 2
            self.head.nose = 1
            self.head.mouth = 1
        self.neck = 1
        self.torso = 1
```

I imagine this is possible with some sort of workaround, yeah?

Comment: Just do what everyone else does.... ' organize' by separating pieces by new lines... Much more clearer that way

Comment: As it stands, the code example is broken. The `__init__` method tries to assign a value to `self.head.eye`, but this is an error because `self.head` has had an `int` assigned to it, which does not have an `eye` attribute.

Answer (score 2):

You can not make a such indentation, because indentatin is used for **parsing python code blocks**, not simply just for **stylish** reasons...

If you want to group them somehow, the you can use a dict as follows:

```
class Bro:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head {
            'head': 1,
            'eye' : 2,
            'nose' : 1,
            'mouth' : 1,
        }
        self.neck = 1
        self.torso = 1
```

but simply that is not a good way, so defining all body parts within dictionary is better

```
class Bro:
    def __init__(self):
        self.body {
            'head': {
                'head': 1,#defining itself
                'eye' : 2,
                'nose' : 1,
                'mouth' : 1,
            },
            'neck' : 1,
            'torso' : 1, 
       }
```

Might be a better approach, but its harder to use since writing `self.nose` is simpler than `self.head.nose` or `self.body['head']['nose']`

Answer (score 0):

Technically, yes it's possible, e.g.:

```
class Bro:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = 1
        if True:
            self.head.eye = 2
            self.head.nose = 1
            self.head.mouth = 1
        self.neck = 1
        self.torso = 1
```

Whether that's a good idea as far as readability goes, I am not sure. I personally would probably not do it.

P.S. One could probably use (abuse?) the `with` statement to make it read better.