# How do you properly add an unnecessary indent (for organisational purposes) in Python without pylint complaining?

Tags: python, pylint

I'm currently using

```
if True:
    ...
```

in order to add an extra indentation for organisational purposes but that will make pylint complain about using-constant-test. Is there some kind of proper statement in Python for this situation (something like `pass`) without abusing the `if` statement like this?

This is not a duplicate of [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8457561/force-an-indent-in-python-code-for-organizational-purposes) since that was not concerned with pylint.

Comment: Can you use some other "organisational feature" to begin with, like separate functions…? That would not only visually organise the code, but do so semantically as well.

Comment: I could but that seems like overkill for my situation.

Comment: I'd argue that if your code is so long without a "natural" break that you need to start organising it, you *should* refactor that so it "naturally" breaks more often.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want the message to stop annoying you, you can disable it with a comment, 
either throughout the file:

```py
# pylint: disable=using-constant-test
if True:
    ...
```

or just for that line:

```py
if True:  # pylint: disable=using-constant-test
    ...
```

Comment: I was hoping for some kind of Python structure that I wasn't aware of but adding ignore statements is not so crazy.